# Are side-effects sometimes necessary when using KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a state variable `s`.

I've got a `.z.ws` hook that responds to websocket messages and runs:

```
.z.ws: {handleMsg x}
```

Do I have to declare `s` as global for `handleMsg` to be able to update `s`?

Ideally, what I'd want is something like:

```
s: handleMsg[s;x]
```

where `handleMsg` is a pure function (it doesn't affect any globals on the inside).

Should I declare `s` as global and then try to do this assignment inside the websocket callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pre-declare variables as global in kdb, they're global if you make them global at any point (and if you reference them as a global).

```
q)func:{x+1}

/s is local and treated as such
q){s:func[1]}[]
2

/it is not a global
q)s
's

/this would make it global
q){`s set func[1]}[]
`s
/or
q){s::func[1]}[]

/now it's global
q)s
2

/but a local of the same name would take preference
q){s:func[100];s}[]
101
q)s
2

/you can force-reference the global if required
q){s:func[100];value `s}[]
2
```

So you're in complete control over what's global, what isn't, when you're referencing a local and when you're referencing a global.